# Book for Learning RAC

Tags: oracle, rac

What is a good book to read to learn about RAC?  I am most interested in the practical end rather than the theory behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [ronr.blogspot.com](http://ronr.blogspot.com/p/books.html) for a plug of and link to a book by Ben Prusinsky and Syed Jaffar Hussain that is very practical. It explains lots of things, and how to do them in great detail. There is lots of hands on experience in it. Very - VERY - nice.

Answer (score 1):

As always, I would start with the [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.portal_db?selected=16&frame=). You'll also need a virtual test environment, check Tim Hall's [articles](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/rac/ArticlesRac.php), they are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions already posted, I highly recommend the Apress edition for 11gR2. I used it extensively to implement our development and production RAC environments after having no previous experience on RAC.  Hope this helps!

Here's a link to the book [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004VJ472I)

Comment: Hi CJ and thanks for your suggestion. I hope you don't mind I smartened up the link you provided.

Comment: Not at all. Still learning the ropes - will keep that tip handy for next time.  Thanks, Jack!